# openapi Enum null values

Tags: java, maven, openapi, swagger-2.0, openapi-generator

I am currently trying to have null values for Enum, as per the OpenAPI specs, this is possible. I am trying to follow the steps as given here

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/enums/

my yaml implementation

```
openapi: 3.0.1

info:
  title: Test
  description: Test API
  contact:
    name: a
    url: http://www.google.com
    email: user@test.com
  version: '1.0'

paths:
  /v1/getItems:
    summary: 'get items'
    description: 'get items'
    post:
      summary: items get
      operationId: getItems
      x-grantTypeRequirement: 'client_credentials'
      tags:
        - items
     
      responses:
        200:
          description: Success
        
components:
  schemas:
    Item:
      title: Order Item
      type: object
      description: 'The order item.'
      required:
        - type
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        type:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/ItemType'

    ItemType:
      description: 'The Type of the Item'
      type: string
      nullable: true
      enum:
        - "PHYSICAL"
        - "DIGITAL"
        - null
```

when I build and run mvn clean install with the changes
nullable:true and enum: with value as null, as shown above I get the below exception

```
[DEBUG] debugging from property return: CodegenProperty{baseName='type', openApiType='ItemType', complexType='ItemType', getter='getType', setter='setType', description='null', datatype='ItemType', datatypeWithEnum='ItemType', dataFormat='null', name='type', min='null', max='null', defaultValue='null', defaultValueWithParam=' = data.type;', baseType='ItemType', containerType='null', title='null', unescapedDescription='null', maxLength=null, minLength=null, pattern='null', example='null', jsonSchema='{
  "$ref" : "#/components/schemas/ItemType"
}', minimum='null', maximum='null', exclusiveMinimum=false, exclusiveMaximum=false, hasMore=false, required=false, secondaryParam=false, hasMoreNonReadOnly=false, isPrimitiveType=false, isModel=false, isContainer=false, isString=false, isNumeric=false, isInteger=false, isLong=false, isNumber=false, isFloat=false, isDouble=false, isByteArray=false, isBinary=false, isFile=false, isBoolean=false, isDate=false, isDateTime=false, isUuid=false, isUri=false, isEmail=false, isFreeFormObject=false, isListContainer=false, isMapContainer=false, isEnum=false, isReadOnly=false, isWriteOnly=false, isNullable=true, isSelfReference=false, _enum=null, allowableValues={values=[PHYSICAL, DIGITAL, null]}, items=null, mostInnerItems=null, vendorExtensions={}, hasValidation=false, isInherited=false, discriminatorValue='null', nameInCamelCase='Type', enumName='null', maxItems=null, minItems=null, isXmlAttribute=false, xmlPrefix='null', xmlName='null', xmlNamespace='null', isXmlWrapped=false}
[ERROR]  unexpected error in Open-API generation
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not process model 'Item'.Please make sure that your schema is correct!
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generateModels (DefaultGenerator.java:472)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate (DefaultGenerator.java:923)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute (CodeGenMojo.java:727)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at com.soebes.maven.plugins.iterator.IteratorMojo.executeMojo (IteratorMojo.java:406)
    at com.soebes.maven.plugins.iterator.IteratorMojo.handlePluginExecution (IteratorMojo.java:305)
    at com.soebes.maven.plugins.iterator.IteratorMojo.execute (IteratorMojo.java:235)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultCodegen.updateCodegenPropertyEnum (DefaultCodegen.java:4304)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultCodegen.postProcessModelsEnum (DefaultCodegen.java:385)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen.postProcessModelsEnum (SpringCodegen.java:815)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.languages.AbstractJavaCodegen.postProcessModels (AbstractJavaCodegen.java:999)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.processModels (DefaultGenerator.java:1233)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generateModels (DefaultGenerator.java:467)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate (DefaultGenerator.java:923)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute (CodeGenMojo.java:727)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at com.soebes.maven.plugins.iterator.IteratorMojo.executeMojo (IteratorMojo.java:406)
    at com.soebes.maven.plugins.iterator.IteratorMojo.handlePluginExecution (IteratorMojo.java:305)
    at com.soebes.maven.plugins.iterator.IteratorMojo.execute (IteratorMojo.java:235)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not process model 'Item'.Please make sure that your schema is correct!
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generateModels (DefaultGenerator.java:472)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate (DefaultGenerator.java:923)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute (CodeGenMojo.java:727)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at com.soebes.maven.plugins.iterator.IteratorMojo.executeMojo (IteratorMojo.java:406)
    at com.soebes.maven.plugins.iterator.IteratorMojo.handlePluginExecution (IteratorMojo.java:305)
    at com.soebes.maven.plugins.iterator.IteratorMojo.execute (IteratorMojo.java:235)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultCodegen.updateCodegenPropertyEnum (DefaultCodegen.java:4304)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultCodegen.postProcessModelsEnum (DefaultCodegen.java:385)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen.postProcessModelsEnum (SpringCodegen.java:815)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.languages.AbstractJavaCodegen.postProcessModels (AbstractJavaCodegen.java:999)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.processModels (DefaultGenerator.java:1233)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generateModels (DefaultGenerator.java:467)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate (DefaultGenerator.java:923)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute (CodeGenMojo.java:727)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at com.soebes.maven.plugins.iterator.IteratorMojo.executeMojo (IteratorMojo.java:406)
    at com.soebes.maven.plugins.iterator.IteratorMojo.handlePluginExecution (IteratorMojo.java:305)
    at com.soebes.maven.plugins.iterator.IteratorMojo.execute (IteratorMojo.java:235)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

any thoughts on what could be causing this exception and what steps should I take to resolve/fix this issue?

Comment: Not very sure. But a guess: The ItemType definition has both `nullable: true` and a null value in the enum list. Looks superfluous. Try deleting the `null` value from the enum list and check.

Comment: if you look here https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/enums/ both are required as per the specs. I did try removing null and nullable: true independently but no luck.

Comment: The issue seems to be persisted in schema model "Item". This has been declared by never used. If you are using any swagger related dependencies can you check whether those versions support nullable enum? If not, try to upgrade them and check.

Comment: @user641887, did you get a solution for this yet? I am also facing exactly same issue.

Comment: hey @RajibBiswas i feel the pain, I did not went that route, took a different approach to solve my problem or I should I say requirements changed for me. But I had raised this in another forum and got a reply. see this and I believe this should resolve your issue. let me know https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Swagger-Open-Source-Tools/Openapi-enum-null-values/m-p/227384/emcs_t/S2h8ZW1haWx8dG9waWNfc3Vic2NyaXB0aW9ufEtYNTkyUElSUFI0SFVVfDIyNzM4NHxTVUJTQ1JJUFRJT05TfGhL#M2235